# Proxy tomcat with haproxy

Tags: docker, haproxy

I am trying to proxy `tomcat` with `haproxy`. Tomcat and haproxy are dockerized inside containers gis-web & web-gateway (both are added to docker bridge network)

I added `sample.war` app to webapps inside `tomcat` and I can see my sample app on `host:8080/sample`

This is the part of HaProxy configuration which does the proxyfing:

```
frontend http-in
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
   
        acl IS_SAMPLE path_beg /sample
    use_backend gis_web if IS_SAMPLE

 backend gis_web
    mode http
    server gis_web_srv gis-web maxconn 1000 check port 8080
```

After setting this up i expected my sample app would be visible at host:80/sample

Also I get this error inside my docker logs:

```
Server gis_web/gis_web_srv is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "No route to host", check duration: 1001ms.
0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
backend 'gis_web' has no server available!
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is this somehow connected with gis_web_srv should that alias be pointing somewhere?

Comment: Is "gis-web" a typo for "gis_web" ?

Comment: No , gis_web is name for backend and gis-web is name of the container which acts as dns for ip host:8080

Comment: So the haproxy container has no route to the gis-web/tomcat container.